# Using host env variable with docker remote API

Tags: docker, env, remoteapi

I'm trying to use the **target** host's env variable to parametrize my container when launching it with the remote API, but none of these worked ...

```
   "Env": [
        "ENV_VAR=`$TEST`",
        "ENV_VAR2=$TEST"
   ],
```

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this ?

Comment: What is not working: $TEST has not the right value? Or ENV_VAR is not defined at all?

Comment: ENV_VAR is set, with the litteral strings \`$TEST\` and $TEST respectivly.

Comment: What command line are you using to invoke that remote API?

Comment: I'm feeding a json while POSTing to : /containers/create?name=myName -d payload.json ("Env" being in the root of the payload)

Answer (score 0):

> I'm feeding a json while POSTing to : `/containers/create?name=myName -d payload.json` ("`Env`" being in the root of the payload)

If `$TEST` is an environment variable from the host, the `payload.json` needs to include its value, not `$TEST`, as the `POST` will not change/interpret `$TEST` (but pass it literally).

If, instead of using a `payload.json` file, you used a command with the json directly in it, you could wrap the json part between *double* quotes: then `$TEST` would be interpreted by the shell.
See "[How to include environment variable in bash line CURL?](https://superuser.com/a/835589/141)"

Comment: The environment variable is meant to be taken from the target host, not the client using the remote API

Comment: @pedro the remote API itself is not like a shell: it won't interpret anything.

Comment: Yeah i understand that, but there could have been a way for the remote docker to start the container using its host env ..., thanks anyway for you time.